# Regarding Pointer to structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a program to implement the virtual software router. My C programming Skills are not that great. When I am going through my skeleton code, I came across this :

```
struct ip *ippacket = (struct ip*) (packet + sizeof(struct sr_ethernet_hdr));
```

Can anybody please explain what exactly it means ?

Comment: Which part(s) of it do you not understand?

Comment: You're creating a virtual software router in a language you don't understand? This cannot end well.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious : Sorry sir, If i was too silly. But I want to learn it no matter what.I am not too naive to C programming, but i am not that well versed with handling pointers. So raised a question.I definitely need support. well, i will stop raising such basic Question from now.

Comment: "I am not too naive to C programming, but i am not that well versed with handling pointers." -- That's a contradiction. In any case, the line of code you gave is *basic* to systems programming, so ... what the Captain said.

Answer (score 1):

For a good understanding look up "pointer arithmetic."

If 'packet' is a pointer to a packet this is adding the size of a packet header, so the result 'ippacket' would be a pointer to the first byte that follows the packet header.

Answer (score 1):

To answer for certain we would have to know how the variable `packet` was declared. I'll assume it is a pointer to a type of size 1, for example `char* packet`.

It appears that `packet` is expected to point to a block of memory that starts with a `struct sr_ethernet_hdr` followed by a `struct ip`, and it is desired that `ippacket` will point to the `struct ip`.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer with name `ippacket` pointing at the adress of a `struct ip` is initialized to point to the address `packet + sizeof(struct sr_ethernet_hdr)` after casting that address to the correct type.

You should not be asking this sort of question on stackoverflow, it doesn't contribute to the community and is too basic to be helpful. Also you need to know this sort of thing already if you are writing a virtual router!